# How do i put a variable from one javascript function to display via another javascript function on an html site

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, global

Im trying to make it so that when i click 'submit', my data gets stored in variables and then when i click 'show' the data gets displayed

this is my js code:

```
var Usrname = "";
var Passwrd = "";

const SignUp = () =>{
    Usrname = document.getElementById("Username").value;
    Passwrd = document.getElementById("Password").value;
};

const Show = (Usrname) =>{

    document.getElementById("usrnmtxt").innerHTML = Usrname;
    document.getElementById("pswrdtxt").innerHTML = Passwrd;
};
```

and this is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body id="BODY">
    
    <form >
        <p>USERNAME</p>
        <input type="text" id="Username"><br>
        <p>PASSWORD</p>
        <input type="text" id="Password"><br>
        <button type="submit" value="submit" onclick=SignUp()>Sign up</button>
    </form>
    <div>
        <button class="Button" id="Show" onclick=Show(Usrname)>SHOW</button>
        <h1 id="usrnmtxt"> - </h1>
        <h1 id="pswrdtxt"> - </h1>
    </div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your issue is that you don't prevent the form from submitting (which in this case will simply reload the page) - the simplest solution is `onclick="SignUp(); return false"` ... also `onclick=Show(Usrname)` can be `onclick="Show()"` and `const Show = (Usrname) =>{` changed to `const Show = () =>{` - as it makes no sense to pass in `Usrname` as an argument since it's a global anyway